# Data Encryption using AES-256-CBC mode openssl , doesnt return the same size of data which doesnt need padding?

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes

I am trying to use openssl AES to encrypt my data i found the pretty nice example in this link ., http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt
but the question i still could found the answer it padding the data although it perform a multiple of key size . 
for example it needs 16 byte as input to encrypt or any multiple of 16
i gave 1024 including the null ., and it still give me an out put of size 1040 , 
but as what i know AES input size  = out put size , if the input is a multiple of 128 bit / 16 byte .
any one tried this example before me or can give me any idea ?|
thanks in Advance .

Comment: You should use AES-CTR instead, or even better, AES-GCM.

Comment: Only 1-16 bytes of overhead is too low. You probably need another 16 for the IV and 16 for the MAC.

Answer (score 4):

Most padding schemes require that some minimum amount of padding *always* be added. This is  (at least primarily) so that on the receiving end, you can look at the last byte (or some small amount of data at the end) and know how much of the data at the end is padding, and how much is real data.

For example, a typical padding scheme puts zero bytes after the data with one byte at the end containing the number of bytes that are padding. For example, if you added 4 bytes of padding, the padding bytes (in hex) would be something like `00 00 00 04`. Another common possibility puts that same value in *all* the padding bytes, so it would look like `04 04 04 04`.

On the receiving end, the algorithm has to be ready to strip off the padding bytes. To do that, it looks at the last byte to tell it how many bytes of data to remove from the end and ignore. If there's no padding present, that's going to contain some value (whatever the last byte in the message happened to be). Since it has no way to know that no padding was added, it looks at that value, and removes that many bytes of data -- only in this case, it's removing actual data instead of padding.

Although it might be possible to devise a padding scheme that avoided adding extra data when/if the input happened to be an exact multiple of the block size, it's a lot simpler to just add at least one byte of padding to every message, so the receiver can count on always reading the last byte and finding how much of what it received is padding.

Comment: +1: Worth noting: the padding scheme most often used is PKCS5, and it traditionally sets not just the tail byte, but all the pad bytes as well, to the byte value of the number of pad bytes. For example. the last three bytes of a padded block that has three bytes of padding will be `0x03,0x03,0x03`. The tricky part is what to do when the input data is a perfect block size. The spec for PKCS5 says to pad en *entire* block of pad bytes.

Comment: There is, in fact, **no** reasonable way to avoid adding a whole block of padding when the original message is an exact multiple of the block size. Why: if `pad(X) = Y` and `pad(Y) = Y`, then `unpad(Y)` would have to be both `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Exactly. An input source that is already perfectly aligned on the algorithm block size *must* have one additional block appended, and that block *must* be full-padding. Otherwise there is no way the reader, who is expecting padding, will know after decryption how much to throw out.

Comment: so i  have a problem ., i need to encrypt x then encrypt y then cambine both of them in one block then decrypt that block .,according to ur note it will my task will not be done! but as what i know , AES should take size of data come up with tha same size unless itneeds paading to reach nearest multiple of 128 ..!
what do you think ? thank you .. :)

Comment: There are a few ways of avoiding padding. One is to use a stream cipher or block cipher in stream cipher (CTR) mode. The other is simply know the length beforehand. Yet another is ciphertext stealing. Getting rid of the IV is a lot harder. Again, it can be done as long as you have something to derive the IV from.